Empty Namespace in Code Coverage After Upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 8 in TeamCity
I'm facing an issue after upgrading my Azure Function App from .NET 6 to .NET 8. When I check the code coverage report in TeamCity, I notice an additional entry labeled

empty namespace name

. This wasn't present before the upgrade, and it seems to include files that were previously categorized correctly under their respective namespaces.
Environment:
.NET 8 (upgraded from .NET 6)
Azure Function App
TeamCity for CI/CD
Has anyone encountered a similar issue when upgrading to .NET 8? How can I fix this

empty namespace name

problem in the code coverage report in TeamCity?
Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Are you trying to upgrade a .NET 6 in-process function to a .NET 8 isolated function?

yes I have upgraded net6 to net8

I am asking inprocess to isolated or isolated to isolated.

Yes Aslesha, isolated to isolated.

How you have deployed your app ?Are you getting the error for the deployed app ?

Try using this in start of file namespace yournamespace;
